# Is an extent used to add new data?

Tags: sql, database, mysql, relational-database, oracle9i

Is an extent used to add new data?what is segment and how is it releted to an extent?

Comment: You can keep the "explicit" diagrams to yourself TYVM :)

Comment: @Billy..This shouldn't be a helper's attitude.Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a nutshell, each non-partioned table, index, table partition etc. has 1 `segment` to hold its data.  Each segment consists of one or more extents.  For a more detailed explanation I'll refer you to the [Oracle 9i Concepts Guide: Logical Database Structures](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10500_01/server.920/a96524/c01_02intro.htm#7490).